# how do I set up a table in a page such that it is flipped?

Tags: tables

I have a table which is too wide to appear horizontally. I want to flip it such that it appears vertically, and put it in a page by itself (no other text appearing in that page). How would I approach it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a possibility

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{pdflscape,booktabs}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{center}
\captionof{table}{My table}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.5\textwidth}p{0.5\textwidth}}
\toprule
col 1 & Col 2\\
\midrule
\lipsum[13] & \lipsum[25]\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{center}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Martin H's answer, you can use the sidewaystable environment from the [rotating package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/rotating/).  Modifying Martin's example, you would have

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
  \centering
  \caption{My table}
  \begin{tabular}{p{0.5\textwidth}p{0.5\textwidth}}
    \hline
    col 1 & Col 2\\
    \hline
    \lipsum[13] & \lipsum[25]\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```