# Table is too wide to fit in one page

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{Cross-sectional regression}
\begin{tabular}{l*{10}{D{.}{.}{-1}}}
\toprule
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(7)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(8)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(9)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(10)}         \\
\midrule
rec                 &    -0.00887         &     -0.0302         &      -0.260         &      -0.203         &      -0.196         &      -0.142         &      -0.224         &      0.0137         &      -0.231         &      0.0640         \\
            &    [0.0523]         &    [0.0803]         &     [0.157]         &     [0.120]         &     [0.136]         &     [0.126]         &     [0.117]         &     [0.122]         &     [0.460]         &     [0.224]         \\
\addlinespace
Constant            &     -0.0912\sym{***}&    -0.00939         &       0.124\sym{***}&      0.0729\sym{**} &       0.112\sym{***}&       0.131\sym{***}&       0.148\sym{***}&       0.121\sym{***}&       0.235\sym{**} &       0.149\sym{***}\\
            &    [0.0100]         &    [0.0148]         &    [0.0290]         &    [0.0231]         &    [0.0264]         &    [0.0249]         &    [0.0237]         &    [0.0252]         &    [0.0817]         &    [0.0406]         \\
\midrule
Observations        &        8088         &        7153         &        6154         &        5313         &        4591         &        3983         &        3553         &        3186         &        2818         &        2441         \\
Adjusted \(R^{2}\)  &      -0.000         &      -0.000         &       0.000         &       0.000         &       0.000         &       0.000         &       0.001         &      -0.000         &      -0.000         &      -0.000         \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{11}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors in brackets}\\
\multicolumn{11}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This is the code I used when trying to use to create a table. When I run it and print out the PDF, the table is way too wide to fit on one page. I've been checking out similar questions to mine and tried what's suggested in those answers, but I haven't really gotten it to work..

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please specify what you want to achieve? Eg. rotate the table 90 degrees? put it on a seperate page rotated?

Comment: ...or shrink to fit, or shrink to known smaller font size, etc.

Comment: @Trefex, in best possible scenario I would like to keep the font size. Therefore i think a rotation by 90 degrees would be suitable. How do i achieve this? Thanks

Comment: Please make sure there’s no question on tex.sx covering your problem before asking a new question. For rotating a table, there’s http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25369/how-to-rotate-a-table and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10101/how-do-i-set-up-a-table-in-a-page-such-that-it-is-flipped, other solutions to overwide tables are given at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39435/how-can-i-center-a-too-wide-table and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63651/how-to-shrink-a-table-automatically-so-that-it-fits-onto-a-page. If none of these works for you, please explain why.

Answer (score 3):

A combination of the following elements will make the table fit inside the text block

- Reduce the amount of intercolumn whitespace by setting `\setlength\tabcolsep{1.5pt}` (default value: `6pt`)
- Use `2.7` instead of `-1` as the specifier for the `D` column type
- Use `\footnotesize` for a 20% (linear) reduction in font size
- Use a "normal-width" text block (e.g., with 1" margins)
- Center-set the entries in the row with the number of observations
- Abbreviate some of the lengthy words in the first column
- Eliminate the white space to the left of the first column and the right of the final column.

(The thin vertical lines at the edges of the table are drawn by the `showframe` option of the `geometry` package.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut command
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{1.5pt} % default value is 6pt
\footnotesize
\centering
\caption{Cross-sectional regression}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{10}{d{2.7}} @{}} 
\toprule
&\mc{(1)} &\mc{(2)} &\mc{(3)} &\mc{(4)} &\mc{(5)} 
&\mc{(6)} &\mc{(7)} &\mc{(8)} &\mc{(9)} &\multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{(10)}  \\
\midrule
rec & -0.00887 & -0.0302 &  -0.260 &  -0.203 &  -0.196 &  -0.142 &  -0.224 &  0.0137 &  -0.231 &  0.0640         \\
    & [0.0523] & [0.0803] & [0.157] & [0.120] & [0.136] & [0.126] & [0.117] & [0.122] & [0.460] & [0.224]         \\
\addlinespace
Const.\    & -0.0912\sym{***}& -0.00939 &   0.124\sym{***}&  0.0729\sym{**} &   0.112\sym{***}&   0.131\sym{***}&   0.148\sym{***}&   0.121\sym{***}&   0.235\sym{**} &   0.149\sym{***}\\
& [0.0100] & [0.0148] & [0.0290] & [0.0231] & [0.0264] & [0.0249] & [0.0237] & [0.0252] & [0.0817] & [0.0406] \\
\midrule
Obs.\ & \mc{8088} & \mc{7153} & \mc{6154} 
& \mc{5313} & \mc{4591} & \mc{3983} & \mc{3553} 
& \mc{3186} & \mc{2818} & \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{2441} \\
Adj.~\(R^{2}\)  &  -0.000 &  -0.000 &   0.000 &   0.000 & 0.000 & 0.000 & 0.001 & -0.000 &  -0.000 & -0.000  \\
\bottomrule \addlinespace
\multicolumn{11}{@{}l}{Standard errors in brackets}\\
\multicolumn{11}{@{}l}{\sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If you're willing to place the table in landscape mode, i.e., rotate it by 90 degrees, by loading the `rotating` package and the `sidewaystable` environment, you can dispense with some of the adjustments above, such as using a smaller font size and abbreviating the words in the first column and still get the table to fit inside the (now wider) text block:

[image]

```
\begin{sidewaystable}
%\footnotesize %% no longer needed
\centering
\caption{Cross-sectional regression}
\smallskip
\begin{tabular}{@{}l*{9}{D{.}{.}{2.7}}d{2.6}@{}}
\toprule
&\mc{(1)} &\mc{(2)} &\mc{(3)} &\mc{(4)} &\mc{(5)} 
&\mc{(6)} &\mc{(7)} &\mc{(8)} &\mc{(9)} &\multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{(10)}  \\
\midrule
rec & -0.00887 & -0.0302 &  -0.260 &  -0.203 &  -0.196 &  -0.142 &  -0.224 &  0.0137 &  -0.231 &  0.0640         \\
    & [0.0523] & [0.0803] & [0.157] & [0.120] & [0.136] & [0.126] & [0.117] & [0.122] & [0.460] & [0.224]         \\
\addlinespace
Constant    & -0.0912\sym{***}& -0.00939 &   0.124\sym{***}&  0.0729\sym{**} &   0.112\sym{***}&   0.131\sym{***}&   0.148\sym{***}&   0.121\sym{***}&   0.235\sym{**} &   0.149\sym{***}\\
& [0.0100] & [0.0148] & [0.0290] & [0.0231] & [0.0264] & [0.0249] & [0.0237] & [0.0252] & [0.0817] & [0.0406] \\
\midrule
Observations & \mc{8088} & \mc{7153} & \mc{6154} 
& \mc{5313} & \mc{4591} & \mc{3983} & \mc{3553} 
& \mc{3186} & \mc{2818} & \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{2441} \\
Adjusted \(R^{2}\)  &  -0.000 &  -0.000 &   0.000 &   0.000 & 0.000 & 0.000 & 0.001 & -0.000 &  -0.000 & -0.000  \\
\bottomrule \addlinespace
\multicolumn{11}{@{}l}{Standard errors in brackets}\\
\multicolumn{11}{@{}l}{\sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pending more details, this is what you could do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \hspace{-3.5cm}
    \def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{tabularx}{1.5\textwidth}{lccXXXXXXXX}
\toprule
  &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(7)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(8)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(9)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(10)}         \\          
\midrule
rec                 &    -0.00887         &     -0.0302         &      -0.260         &      -0.203         &      -0.196         &      -0.142         &      -0.224         &      0.0137         &      -0.231         &      0.0640         \\
            &    [0.0523]         &    [0.0803]         &     [0.157]         &     [0.120]         &     [0.136]         &     [0.126]         &     [0.117]         &     [0.122]         &     [0.460]         &     [0.224]         \\
\addlinespace
Constant            &     -0.0912\sym{***}&    -0.00939         &       0.124\sym{***}&      0.0729\sym{**} &       0.112\sym{***}&       0.131\sym{***}&       0.148\sym{***}&       0.121\sym{***}&       0.235\sym{**} &       0.149\sym{***}\\
            &    [0.0100]         &    [0.0148]         &    [0.0290]         &    [0.0231]         &    [0.0264]         &    [0.0249]         &    [0.0237]         &    [0.0252]         &    [0.0817]         &    [0.0406]         \\
\midrule
Observations        &        8088         &        7153         &        6154         &        5313         &        4591         &        3983         &        3553         &        3186         &        2818         &        2441         \\
Adjusted \(R^{2}\)  &      -0.000         &      -0.000         &       0.000         &       0.000         &       0.000         &       0.000         &       0.001         &      -0.000         &      -0.000         &      -0.000         \\
\bottomrule
    \multicolumn{11}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors in brackets}\\
\multicolumn{11}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This will lead to this result

[image]

The tabularx package provides a new column type 'X' which is what you might be looking for.
I also removed 3.5 cm on the left using hspace and i set the width of the tabular to use 1.5 times the textwidth.

You might have to change the margins or play around with these settings or be more specific :)

Edit: To rotate the table, use the `rotating` package.
Then you can replace \begin{table} with \begin{sidewaystable} and your table is now rotated. Obviously you can remove the hspace and adjust the width of the tabularx environment to your liking...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}[htbp]\centering

\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
    \begin{tabularx}{0.99\textheight}{lccXXXXXXXX}
    \toprule
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}     {(3)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(7)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(8)}           &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(9)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(10)}         \\          
\midrule
rec                 &    -0.00887         &     -0.0302         &      -0.260         &       -0.203         &      -0.196         &      -0.142         &      -0.224         &       0.0137         &      -0.231         &      0.0640         \\
          &    [0.0523]         &    [0.0803]         &     [0.157]         &      [0.120]         &     [0.136]         &     [0.126]         &     [0.117]         &      [0.122]         &     [0.460]         &     [0.224]         \\
\addlinespace
Constant            &     -0.0912\sym{***}&    -0.00939         &       0.124\sym{***}&        0.0729\sym{**} &       0.112\sym{***}&       0.131\sym{***}&       0.148\sym{***}&         0.121\sym{***}&       0.235\sym{**} &       0.149\sym{***}\\
          &    [0.0100]         &    [0.0148]         &    [0.0290]         &     [0.0231]         &    [0.0264]         &    [0.0249]         &    [0.0237]         &     [0.0252]         &    [0.0817]         &    [0.0406]         \\
\midrule
Observations        &        8088         &        7153         &        6154         &           5313         &        4591         &        3983         &        3553         &          3186         &        2818         &        2441         \\
Adjusted \(R^{2}\)  &      -0.000         &      -0.000         &       0.000         &        0.000         &       0.000         &       0.000         &       0.001         &       -0.000         &      -0.000         &      -0.000         \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{11}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors in brackets}\\
\multicolumn{11}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \ (p<0.001\)}\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. This works fine! But if I would like to rotate 90 degrees to keep font size, how will I approach this in the code?

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: I tried the rotating package together with the sidewaystable command. My problem now is that the table is too "long" and stretches out of the page. Do you have any suggestions of how to solve this? Thank you

Comment: @user50270 see my edited answer.

Comment: By using the `X` column type, the numbers will no longer be aligned on their decimal values and the `-` (minus) signs in front of negative numbers will be typeset as dashes rather than as proper minus signs. You may want to mention these features explicitly in the answer.

Comment: @Trefex, thank you for the answer. I'm satisfied with the results

Comment: @user50270 If you accept this answer, please click on the button so other people do not think this post is still unanswered. Cheers!

Comment: @Mico good point. I feel it can be solved by creating a new column type just like you have, but would need more fiddling. Your solution is also nice btw!